# Was Frederick Douglass right that in his day 'religious slaveholders are the worst'? If so why would this be?

Tags: united-states, slavery, christianity

I am quoting from the autobiography of Frederick Douglass (1818-1895), who as many readers will probably know escaped from slavery in Maryland in 1838, settled in Massachusetts and became an anti-slavery (and also women's rights) campaigner. In his 'Narrative of the Life of Frederick Douglass' he describes being owned, hired or lent to several different masters, and observing others.

Douglass states:

> 'Of all the slaveholders with whom I have ever met, religious slaveholders are the worst. I have ever found them the meanest and bassest, and most cruel and cowardly, of all others.'

He gives various examples, such as the Rev. Daniel Weeden of the Reformed Methodist Church

> 'whose maxim was, Behave well or behave ill, it is the duty of a master occasionally to whip a slave, to remind him of his master's authority',

and a Rev. Rigby Hopkins of the same Church who was even worse:

> 'The peculiar feature of his government was that of whipping slaves in advance of deserving it. He always managed to have one or more of his slaves to whip every Monday morning. He did this to alarm their fears, and strike terror into those who escaped [punishment]. His plan was to whip for the smallest offences, to prevent the commission of large ones.'

The book gives several other examples of clergy, lay preachers and Christians known for their piety who were particularly harsh to their slaves, including a group of them who violently suppressed a Sunday School slaves had organized for themselves.

However, Douglass simply states in his book (a very interesting read, by the way) that he found that devout religious (by which he meant Christian) slave owners are the worst, but offers no explanation as to why this should be so.

Is there any evidence as to whether (as a generalization, obviously) he was right? If so, why would that be?

Comment: While the Douglass quotes do not hint in that direction, I imagine that you could easily give a religious justification for abuse against slaves. That would point in the direction of [ritual abuse](https://brissc.org.au/resources/ritual-abuse/) as defined in modern trauma therapy. Because of its "mind control" element (you are supposed to cherish your punishment, as it is god-ordained), this would have a special quality that victims will certainly see as extraordinarily cruel. I wonder if scholars have applied this train of thought to the history of slavery?

Comment: Is this really a historical claim? Wouldn't this be better suited to some sociological or psychological forum? This isn't the kind of thing that a historian can accurately answer.

Comment: This may or may not be a question a historian can answer. A lot was written about slavery in the 19th Century USA, the period is well-documented and the topic has been heavily studied for decades. Yes, Douglass was generalizing from his experience, but was intelligent and perceptive. It is relevant to know if anyone else at the time commented on this. Also, I once spent weeks cataloguing the correspondence of a man who lived in the 1700s. By the end I had a real sense of what he thought and even his implied unspoken values. Someone may have    studied a slave owning clergyman in the same way

Comment: I would not assume that a psychologist or similar could necessarily answer this better than a historian. Since all involved are dead, a psycholgist cannot carry out a proper diagnostic interview. A psychologist would also tend to be less aware than a historian of cultural differences over time, and especially since they cannot interview people from the 19th Century, would be at risk of shoe-horning their experiences into the latest psychological theory based on treating clients in 21st Century California. Psychology has its share of dogma, crank theories and confirmation bias anyway.

Comment: A non-religious master would insist on slaves working hard. So would a religious one. But a religious one, believing a slave had a duty to obey him in all things (not just work), might also feel he had a sacred duty to enforce complete submission in all aspects of a slave's life. A religious one might forbid s;aves amusing themselves or playing games or singing or dancing on Sundays, the slaves one day off; whereas a non-religious one wouldn't care what they did so long as the work was done. Just a theory.

Comment: @davidlol: That seems an absurd generalization over the EXTREMELY wide religious beliefs in 19th century America - several of its founding colonies having originally been diverse religious communities escaping persecution. Knowing a little about the Boer Reform Church, that would seem to be true for a Calvinist slave owner - but that seems less theologically sound for an Episcopalian or Roman Catholic. Perhaps your comment should be justified with an investigation into specific theologies of the time and area. Or are you just riding the current anti-religion train since it's easy to do so?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I intended no generalisation. I merely suggest reasons that might apply in some cases, perhaps those Mr Douglas experienced. The investigation you propose might support or refute it. Knowing a little about the Boer Reform Church, as you do, seems hardly to qualify you to imply that the Church of Scotland (Calvinist) differed from the Church of England (Episcopalian). I myself live in Liverpool, a city embroiled in the Slave Trade which was strongly endorsed, Biblically, by its C of E clergy  (city appointees). I worship weekly and am on no anti-religious bandwagon, I think.

Answer (score -2):

It is unlikely that he was right, and it is unlikely that there is any evidence either way, but it is natural that he said that.

People see patterns everywhere, regardless of whether they exist in reality (the "face on the moon" is the canonical example).

[Frederick Douglass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Douglass#Religious_views)

> held that religious ministers committed a "blasphemy" when they taught [slavery] as sanctioned by religion

IOW, he *expected* religious people to be anti-slavery, and thus was more **sensitive** to religious people being pro-slavery (i.e., has was holding them to a *higher standard* - possibly subconsciously).

Comment: I think you're right, but I think it may be more complicated - there are multiple selection biases involved.  I think the most likely case is that *zealots* are severe in both their piety and in their slave management.  But I don't know where to get data to study the hypothesis that there is a significant difference in between the slave abuses by the zealous, the pious and the agnostic.

Comment: Alternatively, he may be speaking of their moral character, holding people who were religious and should have known better to be behaving worse than the irreligious.

Comment: @MarkOlson: yes, this is what I meant, I now added this explicitly.

Comment: Why was he 'unlikely to be right'? If there's 'no evidence' then that assessment has no factual basis

Comment: @NeMo: in the absence of evidence we have to accept the [null hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis) of lack of effect.

Comment: The evidence is that Douglass said so - a contemporary and eyewitness - if eyewitness is the right word for the subject of these abuses. And Douglass wasn't some Marxist either - he wrote in his book that God had personally intervened in his life to save him from slavery, so it's not like he had some anti-Christian agenda. His statement doesn't prove that it was so, but it *is* evidence.

Comment: @NeMo: believing in God is not the same as being Christian. Testimony of a single witness has little weight.

Comment: One witness has more weight than zero witnesses, which is what has been presented for the contrary case (that religiosity made no difference to cruelty). Re Christianity and belief in God, I am not sure what distinction you're trying to make or why it's relevant.

Comment: @NeMo What statistical analyses did Douglas do? Anecdotal evidence is worthless here. Maybe they were on the whole, maybe they weren't, but Douglas was in no way to know for sure. (And really, no one does. No historian would accept this question's premise; it's not about history.)

Comment: Would anyone say that Samuel Pepys diaries are a 'worthless' source because they were 'just anecdotal'? Of course not. The proper thing to do is compare his accounts with other existing ones. In this case, real historical enquiry would be to read more accounts by slaves (and other eyewitnesses) to see if they corroborate what he said - not just to dismiss it because one finds it uncomfortable. This absolutely is a solid history question.